# Sax parser in tag

Tags: sax, atg

I Am using sax parser in atg project.I'm unable to resolve component for sax parser class which extends content handler.Now existing system working fine
in this way that is reading all xml data once and keeping in collection of object and storing data.As my requirements sax parser should read one tag and should store data one by one so that I'm calling method in ending element to store data .Here I'm facing problem unable to inject component that's stores data in dB

Comment: Please, share what you have so far and why it does not work.

Comment: @OliverGondža ,thanks for reply.Im using atg framework .Im unable to inject any component for sax parser class.

Comment: @OliverGondža , i have class public class TRUProfileHandler extends DefaultHandler  for this class i have properity file conatins    like this $class=com.tru.feedprocessor.tol.profile.handler.TRUProfileHandler
$scope=global .For this if inject my database component its throwing null pointer exception

Comment: can you provide a more detailed sample with xml doc and sax code?

Comment: I think it could be a classpath or dependency injection issue. You can manually compile the TRUProfileHandler.java file in command prompt and add TRUProfileHandler.class in the build path of the project to fix the classpath issue. If it is a dependency issue, you have to check all the dependent classes in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use TRUProfileHandler as component for dependency injection, you should extends from GenericService, so I think this a cause of problem. Another way, you can create a component and in this component use instance of TRUProfileHandler which extends from DefaultHandler. so in other words, you shoul incapsulate sax parser in component.